# Android ndk OpenGL texture recovery

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, textures

Recomened to call onResume and onPause events for GLSurface in Activity.

But when i do it, textures faile and i see only white screen and error in log:

```
<gl_draw_error_checks:418>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

In [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/fnPA0rp_UvU) thread writes:

> OpenGL implementation may always forcibly dispose context (see
>   EGL_CONTEXT_LOST error description in eglMakeCurrent and
>   eglSwapBuffer), in such case you are forced to fully restore GL
>   resources. This is low level OS behavior and cannot be changed or
>   workaround.

How can i do it? Any tutorials?

Comment: It says you lose the EGL context so that you have to reinitialize it along with textures. Basically you do the same things that you have done for initializing the context and the texture onResume event. If you are going fully native, then you can take a look at native-activity sample from NDK samples which covers the states that the app is in.

Comment: @user2359247 i have Activity and GLSurface in java =/

Comment: Do initialization in onResume, rather than onCreate.  For a working example of an app using GLSurfaceView, see https://code.google.com/p/android-breakout/ .  (It's entirely in Java, but it sounds like your problems stem from using GLSurfaceView, so that shouldn't matter.)